# Why is VBA creating a folder on ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

This is supposed to save the currently active workbook or worksheet to a path and file name provided. The extension ".xls" is used so that the exported file is a Excel 97-2003 Workbook.

It saves the Workbook or Worksheet but has a folder included in them. Let's say the file name was "Master.xls", `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` works but the VBA seem to include a folder named "Master_files" next to it as if it were saved as a web file. How can I disable this?

Note that the sheet came from an online database, when I click the link to export the records into an Excel sheet it doesn't download it but instead opens it straight from web to my Excel application which is why I created this SaveAs code.

Comment: Did you declare `Path` as a variable, or are you using `ThisWorkbook.Path`?

Comment: Have you / between Path and Filename to separate the path from the file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to expressly specify the format:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8
```

Otherwise, it is saving as HTML, along with the `_files`, because you got it from the Web (I think).  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) says:

> For an existing file, the default format is the last file format specified

which I am guessing is HTML for your situation.

`xlExcel8` is the constant to use for `.xls` files per [Ron de Bruin's reference](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm).

Comment: Ah there we go. I checked the available constants though but if you didn't tell me to use xlExcel8 I wouldn't know which one to use as none of them say "Excel 97-2003 Workbook" :D